# Play sound on webpage

Tags: php, ubuntu, lamp, shell-exec

At my workplace, I was asked to resolve when an inductive loop busy by a car, a webpage will sound a warning while the loop is busy. The created page will opened non-stop on the dispatcher PC browser. I got to the point where I connected the loop to arduino nano + ethernet shield, if I open the link "http://192.168.1.175/?7" it gives 0 or 1 answer (0 if the loop is not busy, 1 if the loop is busy ). How can I do this on a website? The server is a LAMP ubuntu. All this is because the dispatcher does not see the entrance, so he does not know when to open the gate, but because of the electric gate, a loop is already installed.
Sorry for the bad English.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: What is the problem? Do you receive error when using `shell_exec`? I'm not sure I follow question either... do you have some scanner that is reading when cars pass by and you want to execute command after each car passing?

Comment: Well, you would have to execute that `wget` command using the `shell_exec` function (or some similar function), which I cannot see in the code you posted. But apart from that: why would you want to execute that as a shell command in the first place? Why not make that request that resource from within php itself and saving all the hassle shell functions pose?

Comment: @user3783243 Yes, i use for alpr based gate, but i want to play alert sound if a car is parked in front of the gate. An induction loop is dug into the ground.

Comment: @arkascha Good idea, how i request that resource from within php itself, and do while loop every second?

Comment: @pallasattila `curl` or `file_get_contents` should be able to make requests for you

Comment: The possible solution depends on the actual situation which you did not explain. Seems like you are trying to implement some form of monitoring here. If that is limited to a short period of time, so some seconds up to maybe a few minutes then this can be done in pure php, you 'd have to take care to write and flush the output on a regular base so that the client does not disconnect due to inactivity. Otherwise and in general such tasks are better implemented by using client side logic, so javascript inside the browser which make regular requests or uses a web socket to receive continuous data.

Comment: @arkascha This page would run from 0-24 hours on the dispatcher colleague’s browser and will sound a warning if a car is parked in front of the gate. (so if the output of "http://192.168.1.175/?7" is "1").

Comment: You create a static web gui using html or php, inside that you use javascript to pull data from the backend, on the backend you use php to access the hardware and fetch the actual data.

Comment: @arkascha I tried this code:   
I tried the do while loop and if in php code, if statement true: echo ' <embed src="/var/www/html/alpr/touched.mp3" autostart="true" loop="true" hidden="true"> ';, this working, but!! Infinity loop and stuck page loading forever. Unfortunately, this PHP and JavaScript doesn't work for me. :(      I would like to get http://192.168.1.175/?7 output if output "1" play alert sound, if "0" does nothing and repeat this every second while the page is opened.

Comment: I very well understood before what you are trying to do. And if you implement an infinite loop and output things then obviously your page will load forever, since it has never finished. That is why I pointed out that you need to flush the output in between. A pure php based logic won't work though, that is not what php is for. And your server and client will terminate the request eventually. Which is why you need to switch and use client side logic. All you state about that is "PHP and JavaScript doesn't work", but you forgot to 1. mention _why_ not and 2. what you actually tried.

Comment: @arkascha I tried this: 
<script type="text/javascript"  src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0-beta1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javacript">
$.getJSON("loopstatus.json", function(json) {
    if(json.signal == 1){ 
 alert("The loop is busy. ");   
} 
});
</script>

loopstatus.json:
{"signal":"1"}

The json file overwrite every second with actual status.

Not working.

Comment: Sorry, but I fail to understand what you mean by that. So you succeeded in polling the current state on a per second rate. That is pretty fast, you will have to use a web socket instead for such a rate. But if you received the data you desire, then what is the problem? Sounds to me like you have an issue with visualization but not with data retrieval. Since you did not tell us what you actually want to do with the data we cannot help with that.

Comment: @arkascha I run bash script in crontab every 2 second, and write it to the “loopstatus.json” file to get the actual value (0 or 1). The loopstatus.json file content: {"loop":"0"}  . Can I if statement with javascript? Read the loopstatus.json file continuously, If loop value "1" play alert sound on webpage (The audio file is in the same folder as the php page.) if  loop value "0" do nothing. Thanks for help!

Comment: You load a web ui and javascript into the browser via a static setup, no php required for that. Your javascript logic opens a web socket to the server, you can use php for the backend logic. Javascript sends a request through the web socket, php receives the request, checks the file and responds back to javascript in whatever manner you want. Javascript can process that response and do whatever you like in the browser.

Comment: It could be that we deal with a classical AB problem here. So please invest some time, revise your question (there is a "edit" link below it): explain exactly what it actually is you want to achieve, not how you think you might be able to achieve it.

Comment: Reads like the solution I explained a few times should be the right approach.

Comment: @arkascha 
`
 setInterval(function() { 
  console.log('test');
  $.getJSON( 'loopstatus.json', function( data ) {
        var jsondata = data["signal"];

    for(index = 0; index<jsondata.length; ++ index){

    }
 if (jsondata != 0) {
var audio = new Audio('touched.mp3');
audio.play();
}
 
  })
  .error(function(error){
 
  });      
},
3000);
'


This code with Microsoft Edge working good. :) Chrome error message: Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: play() failed because the user didn't interact with the document first. This is good for me.

Comment: I cannot say anything to that few lines, I have no idea in what context they are implemented. If you say things are good, then fine! Have fun!